# Error reading .txt and splitting a list with commas

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm developing a program that choose a random element from a list. The elements are stored in a .txt file separated with commas.

Example: the .txt files contains

```
spam,eggs,bacon
```

So I use this code that returns a list with the 3 elements.

```
f = open("list.txt", "r")

_list_raw = f.read()

_list = (str(_list_raw))

_list_split = _list.split(",")

f.close()

return _list_split
```

_list_split would be [spam, eggs, bacon]

The problem is that if the .txt is empty, this function returns me a list of len = 1 which contains the element ''. I don't understand what is happening here.

```
expected result = [] len = 0
obtained result =[''] len = 1
```

So this cause a lot of problems, if I append an element to this list, I obtain something like this in the .txt

```
,eggs,bacon
```

How can I solve this? Thank you!

Comment: it's returning `['']` because it read empty string from file. Try `_list_split = _list.split(",") if _list else []`

Comment: try strip on this string `str(_list_raw).strip()`

Comment: Thank you! It's solved now. :) the if/else worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue is in line `_list = (str(_list_raw))` if file is empty you explicetly create an empty string which will be inserted to the list, try to use code above:

```py
try:
    with open("list.txt", "r") as f:
        _list_raw = f.read()    
except:
    return []
else:
    return _list_raw.split(",") if _list_raw else []
```

Comment: Oh, that code is nice because it also solves the problem of a missing .txt file. I have another function with w+ that takes _list_split as argument to save the list, so with an empty list as an exception that problem would be solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
expected result = [] len = 0
obtained result = [''] len = 1
```

This behavior is because in the second case, you have a list that has an element inside it. It may be an "empty" string, but it is an element nonetheless.

One way to go about fixing your problem would be:

```
if not _list_split[0]:
    _list_split = []
```

This condition will check if the first element of `_list_split` is an empty string, which will only happen if the file is indeed empty.

Comment: Oh, I understand now. Thanks for replying! :)

Comment: No problem! If you think this has answered your question and could be useful to someone that comes across the same problem, please mark it as accepted. Cheers :)